# How to use concepts to retrieve the number of fields in a class?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, structured-bindings

I had the bright idea that I could use concepts and structured bindings to figure out the number of fields in a struct and then dispatch based on this. The code we came up with is

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept HasOneMember = requires (T const & t) {
    [](T t){
        auto [a]=t;
        return 0;
    }(t);
};


template <typename T>
concept HasTwoMember = requires (T const & t) {
    [](T t){
        auto [a,b]=t;
        return 0;
    }(t);
};


template <typename T> requires HasOneMember<T>
auto foo(T t)
{
    auto & [a]=t;
    std::cout << "has one member " << a <<  std::endl;
}

template <typename T> requires HasTwoMember<T>
auto foo(T t)
{
    auto & [a,b]=t;
    std::cout << "has not one member "<< a << " " << b << std::endl;
}


int main(){
    struct One {
        int a;
    };
    struct Two {
        int b;
        int c;
    };

    foo(One{7});
    foo(Two{42, 8});
}
```

For clang this works

```
has one member 7
has not one member 42 8
```

is the output. However for gcc this does not.

https://godbolt.org/z/vdq6Koezc

I'm curious. Is this because the code is illegal and should not work or does GCC have a bug?

Maybe it is possible to tweak the code so it works in GCC also?

It also compiles for MSVC.

Comment: As the linked duplicate says, GCC is correct in rejecting it, but you don't need a lambda and structured bindings to test the number of members of an aggregate class (at least if it doesn't contain arrays). You only need to define a type with a conversion operator to any type and then you can test whether a temporary construction (includes destructor test) or a placement `new` (doesn't include destructor test) works with the number of arguments required: https://godbolt.org/z/e9qY1s1qe

Comment: I'm curious why you added the ``::new((void*)nullptr)`` prefix. I get a working result without it. Is there some special case this solves? See https://godbolt.org/z/aG9748Kac

Comment: The expression `T{...}` requires that the destructor of the class is non-deleted and accessible. The version with `new` doesn't require that. Granted, this is a rather unusual edge case: https://godbolt.org/z/GojdnP9q9 vs https://godbolt.org/z/nsh7ab9h5.

Comment: Btw, I should have maybe added extra braces, e.g. `T{{Any},{Any},{Any}};` instead of `T{Any,Any,Any};`. This way, I think, arrays should be counted only once, as they would be in structured bindings. On the other hand this seems to cause some issues with reference members. I intended the second conversion function to be used for lvalue reference members, but Clang and GCC have some disagreement about how this works in the first place. So I am not sure at the moment, whether reference members ought to work in either version.

Comment: Well and with reference members the `HasOneMember<T> &&` approach of refinement obviously doesn't work. I didn't think that through properly.